# UITableViewContorller (Static) Size

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have two different problems with my Static `UITableView`.

**1. The height of the table:**
I have 4 cells in my table, the fourth one is going out from the screen size.
(the table are bigger than the screen).
how can i allow scrolling to the size of the table?

**2. Scrolling Horizontal**
 I don't know why, but when I run the app, I can scroll horizontal the all table to the left side.
Why does it happen? how can I fix it?

thank you!

Comment: Are you using Objective C  ??

Comment: Please provide some code. Makes it a lot easier! Otherwise it will be hard to help you

Comment: If you are using story board for designing the tableView set the constraint relative to main view, if you are dong it programmatically, then you need to set the frame of table based on screen size. I think you have given larger width as well as height than the screen size. If you need more help, show me the code ..

Comment: I'm using story board for this, so i haven't any code to show... 
i'm not find the right place on the story board to change the size.
can you send me photo of this?
and thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `top,bottom,leading and trailing constraint` from the interface builder (i.e. storyboard) to your tableview. Something like below screenshot,

[image]

In the screenshot constrains got setting for address label, you need to select your `tableview` and need to set four constraints.

If you totally unaware of `autolayout` then first learn it. refer some tutorial like : [Raywenderlich's tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) or [Appcoda's tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/).